# CSS image cropping and resize

Tags: html, css

I have the problem where I need to crop a bounding box of an image in CSS.

[image: Bounding box to crop]

I'm given an image similar to the above (without the drawing of course) and the goal is to crop the black square according to the percentage values, which are relative to the origin of the image (top left corner is standard for images), and then show that image fully maximized

I would like to perform this task without any JS if it's possible, that is, I want to use an  tag or ideally i could do it on any tag.

My original idea was to use negative `margin` with overflow hidden, like so:

```html
<div class="overflow-hidden">
  <div style="margin: -19% 22% -26% -22%;">
    <img>
  </div>
</div>
```

but unfortunately the margin property seems to be relative to the width of the parent only. It also seems quite hacky.

I also tried clip-path, but I can't figure out how to resize the clipped objected to fit the parent container.

Comment: Wy not just edit the photo in PhotoShop? It will save you allot of time.

Comment: I have thousands of pictures of dynamically sized bounding boxes. It is not feasible to me to do that

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```css
.croppedImg {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.croppedImg>* {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.croppedImg>*::before {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  padding-top: 100%;
}

.croppedImg>*>img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  min-height: calc(100% + 19% + 26%);
  min-width: calc(100% + 22% + 22%);
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  inset: -19% -22% -26% -22%;

  transition: all 500ms 0ms ease-in-out;
}

.croppedImg:hover>*>img {
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  inset: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="croppedImg" style="width: 500px">
  <div>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/500">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is promising. Unfortunately it seems like it doesn't crop correctly. Substituting the image I supplied it does not seem to zoom in properly